# NSMutableArray withObject(UIImageView *)

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, nsmutablearray

I am trying to load an NSMutableArray with UIImageViews.  Everything is going fine with that.

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to use the objects when they are in the mutable array.

Here is some code:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray new];
[array loadWithObject:(UIImageView *)imageView];
[imageView release];
```

That kind of sets up what I've done.  Here's what I want to do:

```
[array objectAtIndex:5].center = GCRectMake(0, 0);
```

but that doesn't work.  How can I do this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I'll explain the problems you're having. The way to do what you are trying to do is the following:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObject:imageView];
[imageView release];
[[array objectAtIndex:0] setCenter:CGPointMake(0.0,0.0)];
```

First, there is no method `-[NSMutableArray loadWithObject:]`. Likewise, for your example, you don't really even need a mutable array. Mutable objects have their place, but I usually try to use immutable ones when it makes sense to; as such, I've used `NSArray`.

Next, you never need to typecast objects when you're adding them to an array. There are a few reasons wherefore your example didn't work:

1. You were accessing the sixth (starting at one) object in the array. Was there an instance of `UIImageView` at that index?
2. For some reason, dot-notation for getters and setters only works when the compiler knows the type of the object you're sending a message to. Since the type of an object that is coming out of an array is not clear at compile-time, you can't use dot-notation. Instead, just use old-fashioned Objective-C method-sending syntax ("brackets and colons").
3. Finally, it's **Core Graphics**, not **Gore Craphics**: hence the prefix is `CG`, not `GC`. Also, `-[UIImageView setCenter:]` takes a `CGPoint`, not `CGRect`. So the function you wanted was `CGPointMake`.

Best of luck to you! Let me know if this helps clear some things up.

Comment: Thanks.  Sorry about the GC and RectMake typos.  I had those in my code already.  I just tried to summarize what I had done.  The thing I needed was the setCenter: thing.  Works great.  Thanks again.

Comment: Okay, new question.  How can I get the height/width of the UIImageView frame without using the dot-notation?

Comment: Ooops, here's the confusing part: dot-notation for Objective-C objects only works for clearly typed objects, but dot-notation for normal C structs works just as always. Since `CGRect` is a struct, just try the following: `CGFloat height = [(UIImageView *)[arr objectAtIndex:5] frame].size.height;`.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should refer [NSMutableArray](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

However, I am just giving an overview of NSMutableArray.

- NSMutableArray = Next Step (NS) Mutable Array
- Mutable means array can be modified as and when required.
- Now, This mutable array can hold any kind of objects.
- Assume that I want to store strings in an array. I would write following statements.

`NSMutableArray *anArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`
`[anArray addObject:@"Sagar"];`
`[anArray addObject:@"pureman"];`
`[anArray addObject:@"Samir"];`

- Here, I found that you need to store imageViews in your requirements.

`NSMutableArray *anArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`
`UIImageView *imgV1=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,50,60,70)];`
`UIImageView *imgV2=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,110,60,70)];`
`UIImageView *imgV3=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,170,60,70)];`
`UIImageView *imgV4=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,210,60,70)];`
`[anArray addObject:imgV1];`
`[anArray addObject:imgV2];`
`[anArray addObject:imgV3];`
`[anArray addObject:imgV4];`

- Now, once ImageViews are added to array, release imageviews as array has it's retain count.

`[imgV1 release];`
`[imgV2 release];`
`[imgV3 release];`
`[imgV4 release];`

- Above code will add images to NSMutableArray
- When you use one of the image from an array, just write down this thing 
  `UIImageView *x=[anArray objectAtIndex:0];`
- Hope Above descriptions work for you.
- Add comment, if you don't understood.